# Is it possible to return HttpStatus status which is not from HttpStatus enum in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-codes

I want to return , **555 status code in response**.

I have checked ResponseEntity class of spring framework.

I can see all constructors accept only particular codes from HttpStatus enum.
This can be achieved by ,

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body("Custom string answer");
```

**Is there any way to return status code like 555?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using the Spring `ResponseEntity`.

But you can always get a hold of the underlying `HttpServletResponse` and do a `response.setStatus(555)`.

As a side note, if your question was *"is it OK to return non-standard HTTP codes in this scenario?"*, the answer would've probably been *"no"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Spring:

```
ResponseEntity.status(555).body("String or obj")
```